# Bootbox prompt not working as it should

Tags: javascript, bootbox

When ever i use bootbox prompt, the script does not pause for a while to accept input from a user like javascript prompt works, The whole program runs without getting an input from a user. i am not sure why? Any help is appreciable.

```
this.num = bootbox.prompt("Enter a number of nodes" , function(result)
        {
            if(result == null)
            {
                console.log("Cancelled");
            }else{

                return result;
            }
        });

        console.log(this.num);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootbox dialogs are not blocking events, so *everything* that **needs** to happen only when the dialog is dismissed needs to be in the callback function.

This is covered [on the Bootbox site](http://bootboxjs.com/#getting-started):

> The only required argument for `alert` calls is `message`; `callback` is
>   required for `confirm` and `prompt` calls in order to determine what the
>   user's response was. Even when calling `alert` a callback is useful to
>   determine when the user dismissed the dialog since our wrapper methods
>   **can't** & **don't** block like their native counterparts; they are
>   asynchronous rather than synchronous.

This will be true of *any* non-native modals, not just Bootbox (and the underlying Bootstrap modals).